Split duplicated by the number of reps
I have a sheet need to be split and transpose, the other col will be duplicated by the number of Reps and the other column Only the first record from each rep gets copied, the "repeat" is left blank
Heres the sheet for your reference
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IhjE3r6DpOF-tcnzk9ITvLLLv-8KzyMVJ-2BM3_8KRM/edit#gid=2086741331
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IhjE3r6DpOF-tcnzk9ITvLLLv-8KzyMVJ-2BM3_8KRM/edit#gid=2086741331

@rockinfreakshow I have new data sheet, can you try it there? I lost track when there are multiple columns. thank you "new" sheet in the file


You may try:
=reduce(A1:G1,F2:F6,lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,if(c="",tocol(,1),let(Σ,split(c,"; ",0),a,offset(c,,-5),g,offset(c,,1),Λ,counta(Σ),hstack(wrapcols(a,Λ,a),offset(c,,-4,,4),tocol(Σ),wrapcols(g,Λ,g))))))))


UPDATED FORMULA:
=reduce(A1:J1,B2:B3,lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,if(c="",tocol(,1),let(Σ,split(c,"; ",0),a,offset(c,,-1),cdef,offset(c,,1,,4),ij,offset(c,,7,,2),Λ,counta(Σ),hstack(wrapcols(a,Λ,a),tocol(Σ),chooserows(cdef,sequence(Λ,1,1,0)),offset(c,,5,,2),chooserows(ij,sequence(Λ,1,1,0)))))))))


I have new data sheet, can you try it there? I lost track when there are multiple columns. thank you "new" sheet in the file

try the updated formula added to the answer
